# Query about initialise non-static data member in c14

Tags: c++, c++14

I am a student and beginner of programming. I want to initialise non-static data member in class but got warning like " warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]".

It is a c11 style and I need to convert it to c14. I tried to rewrite it to c14 style but failed many times. My textbook said little about how to do it. Could anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Mycode like:

```
public:
    std::vector<bool>IfHasWalls = {true, true, true, true};
    bool Path = false;
    bool Passed = false;
};
```

Comment: It's the same in C++14. Check you compiler flags.

Comment: Maybe you should change your compiler settings to compile as C++11 or C++14.

Comment: It sounds like you are using an old C++ compiler that's configured for C++03 by default. Did you try compiling with the `-std=c++11` option?

Comment: Thanks guys! Maybe there is something wrong with my compiler. I will check it now.